# Prestashop 1.7 , Hide Shipping Price (which always shows free) before the Shipping carrier step

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

Using Prestashop 1.7.6
I have a question regarding Free shipping, as you all know that it always shows Free (because it is selected by default in back office carriers) until it has been changed in carrier selection step.

so what I need guidance on is that I want to hide the shipping cost until "shipping method" step in check out. (or possibly if it says "To be calculated on next step" )

here is the cartpresenter.php code , which i guess shall need modifying ?

```
if (isset($deliveryOptionList) && count($deliveryOptionList) > 0) {
            foreach ($deliveryOptionList as $option) {
                foreach ($option as $currentCarrier) {
                    if (isset($currentCarrier['is_free']) && $currentCarrier['is_free'] > 0) {
                        $shippingDisplayValue = $this->translator->trans('Free', [], 'Shop.Theme.Checkout');
                        break 2;
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create a theme and modify smarty templates :

*For the cart*

Copy to your theme and modify **/themes/classic/templates/checkout/_partials/cart-detailed-totals.tpl** and insert a condition at line 31 and close it at line 47:

```
<div class="card-block">
  {foreach from=$cart.subtotals item="subtotal"}
    {if $subtotal && $subtotal.value|count_characters > 0 && $subtotal.type !== 'tax'}
        {if $subtotal.type === 'shipping' && $subtotal.amount > 0} {* line added *}
        <div class="cart-summary-line" id="cart-subtotal-{$subtotal.type}">
          <span class="label{if 'products' === $subtotal.type} js-subtotal{/if}">
            {if 'products' == $subtotal.type}
              {$cart.summary_string}
            {else}
              {$subtotal.label}
            {/if}
          </span>
          <span class="value">
            {if 'discount' == $subtotal.type}-&nbsp;{/if}{$subtotal.value}
          </span>
          {if $subtotal.type === 'shipping'}
              <div><small class="value">{hook h='displayCheckoutSubtotalDetails' subtotal=$subtotal}</small></div>
          {/if}
        </div>
     {/if}  {* line added *}
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
</div>
```

*For the checkout*

Just do the same for file **/themes/classic/templates/checkout/_partials/cart-summary-subtotals.tpl**

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for replying, The cart-summary-subtotals.tpl file does not have such code, and this is actually what need to modify for. the code in this file is.

`<div class="cart-summary-subtotals-container">
  {foreach from=$cart.subtotals item="subtotal"}
    {if $subtotal && $subtotal.value|count_characters > 0 && $subtotal.type !== 'tax'}
      <div class="cart-summary-line cart-summary-subtotals" id="cart-subtotal-{$subtotal.type}">
        <span class="label">{$subtotal.label}</span>
        <span class="value">{$subtotal.value}</span>
      </div>
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
</div> `